# Get fullcalendar business-hours on resize events

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have implemented full calendar to maintain some events. Now the fullcalendar is implemented with some default business hours. Lets say I have set business hours from 10:00 to 17:00 hours.

Now I am creating the event from 15:30 to 16:30 hours. Now I when I resize the event and stretch it and end it to 17:30, which is out of the business hours, I want it to revert the changes.

Following is how I have initialised the fullcalendar:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  header: {
      left: '',
      center: '',
      right: '',
  },
  firstDay: 0,
  editable: true,
  selectable: true,
  defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
  columnFormat: 'dddd',
  events: events_data,
  eventResize: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
    console.log($(this).businessHours);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `eventResize` function, you can check the `event` parameter and check the input.

```
function isBusinessHour(event) {
    // Check if your event.start and event.end is in business hours
    // Using moment functions such as isBetween()
}

eventResize: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
  if (!isBusinessHour(event))
      revertFunc();
}
```

Comment: Exactly My concern. How will you be able to know it the event start is in business hours or not.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can set the "eventConstraint" option to "businessHours":

```
eventConstraint: "businessHours"
```

The documentation for this setting says:

> If "businessHours" is given, events being dragged or resized must be
>   fully contained within the week’s business hours (Monday-Friday
>   9am-5pm by default). A custom businessHours value will be respected.

See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventConstraint for more details.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work, even with the version 4.
You need to compare values for event and those of business Hours:`

```
eventDrop: function(info) {

   var format = 'HH:mm';

   // get moment as time:min only
   var ies = moment(info.event.start);
   var tes = ies.hours()+':'+ies.minutes();
   var event_start = moment(tes,format); 

   var iee = moment(info.event.end);
   var tee = iee.hours()+':'+iee.minutes();
   var event_end = moment(tee,format); 

   // get business hours
   var bh_start = moment(calendar.getOption('businessHours')['startTime'],format);
   var bh_end = moment(calendar.getOption('businessHours')['endTime'],format);

   if ( event_start.isBefore( bh_start ) || event_end.isAfter( bh_end )) {
      console.log(' out of busqiness hours');
      info.revert();
      return false;
   }
}
```